# How do I import local po files?

Tags: i18n-l10n, 9

There is no /admin/config/regional/translate/import page in Drupal 9 now, which exists in Drupal 7. So I don't know how to import manually translated PO files.

Answer (score 0):

You must have forgot to enable the **Interface Translation** core submodule, which provides **Interface Translation Import** at `/admin/config/regional/translate/import`.

D9 and D7 have a nearly identical UI for translation import that works the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I did enalbe the Interface Translation module. It turned out there was a CSS sinppet which hide the second secondary tab in my administration theme. :-(